# Command for increasing the volume of mp3 with lame

Tags: lame

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 (mostly Unity 2D) and I want to use lame in the terminal. I had been using it as an mp3 amplifier, but I forgot the command, all I remember is:

```
lame scale-<scale you want to increase> <infile> <outfile>
```

But it shows:

```
lame: excess arg Because.mp3 out
```

Because.mp3 is the filename.

Can anyone tell me the command for it?

Answer (score 20):

You have to use:

```
lame --scale <scale you want to increase> <infile> <outfile>
```

So that would be in your example:

```
lame --scale 3 Because.mp3 Because_loud.mp3
```

Comment: well it says 
Could not find "Because.mp3".
Can't init infile 'Because.mp3

the file is in /home/cheenu/beeatles/love

Comment: then you either have to go to that dir (cd /home/cheenu/beeatles/love) before executing the command or add this to the filenames.
lame --scale 3 /home/cheenu/beeatles/love/Because.mp3 /path/to/output/Because_load.mp3
(tab will help you complete the path/filenames)

Answer (score 3):

You should properly escape filenames if they contain spaces, either surrounding them with double quotes or by using the "\" escape character.

```
lame --scale 3 "Because you should escape.mp3" out.mp3
lame --scale 3 Because\ you\ should\ escape.mp3 out.mp3
```

If you do not escape, bash will pass to lame just *Because* as its input file, and lame will exit with an error.